# Why variance specifier can only be declare on Interface or delegate

Tags: c#, covariance

I have a class that have a type parameter that I would like to assign to a more generic type parameter:

```
public StrategyContext<T> : where T : IStrategy {}
```

`StrategyContext` is a class to help designing unit test. Using xUnit and the `Theroy` attribute I can assert some common behavior to all my strategy. For example:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(typeof(LeftStrategy))]
[InlineData(typeof(RightStrategy))]
public void HasAName(Type contextType)
{
    Type strategy = typeof(StrategyContext<>);
    var context = (StrategyContext<IStrategy>)Activator.CreateInstance(strategy.MakeGenericType(contextType));
}
```

Unfortunatly the runtime can not convert from a `StrategyContext<LeftStrategy>` to `StrategyContext<IStrategy>`

So I thought that covariance is what I needed but it is not possible to declare the class as:

```
public StrategyContext<out T> : where T : IStrategy {}
```

Any other solution?

Comment: I think it's an artificial limitation, because in Scala you can do this

Comment: @SargeBorsch I have the same impression

Comment: btw, there are also many other things that can't be done in C# but can be done in Scala or Haskell. So if you are not forced by someone else to use C#, it may be a good idea to switch the language until it's not too late...

Comment: @SargeBorsch I would love to but that is not my decision ;)